# Why there is a blank between each char I wrote to a file with WriteFile?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode

Here's my code:

```
WCHAR msg[] = L"ReplaceFile:";
::WriteFile( hFile, msg, lstrlenW(msg) * sizeof(WCHAR), &nBytes, NULL );
```

I created this file with OPEN_ALWAYS mode, and I'm going to write some const string to this file. The file display the "ReplaceFile" like this:
R e p l a c e F i l e.

Can somebody tell me how to make it normal and why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wide characters, such as those with the `L` prefix, take 2 bytes per character (on Windows). You need to change the string to a different encoding that works on a byte level, such as Windows default code page for your locale.

Comment: A better choice is UTF-8. Stay away from storing strings using locales.

Comment: Please define "normal". UTF16 is quite normal to me.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Wide characters take 2 or 4 bytes per character (codepoint) in UTF-16. You are confusing *codepoint* with *codeunit*. A codeunit takes 2 bytes with UTF-16.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you can't make a blanket statement like that unless you know how the file is going to be used.  If you're feeding it to another Windows application there's a good chance UTF-8 won't work. I too wish the whole world would standardize on UTF-8, but sometimes you have no choice but to hold your nose.

Comment: @IInspectable I suppose I could have been more precise and said `wchar_t` instead of "wide character", and pointed out that there are some small number of characters that don't fit into a single `wchar_t`. But I didn't feel the need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WCHAR` is an alias for `wchar_t`, which is 2 bytes in size on Windows.  Wide strings on Windows are encoded in **UTF-16LE**. In UTF-16, each element (called a codeunit) is 2-bytes (16 bits) in size, where Unicode codepoints U-0000 - U-FFFF take up one codeunit, and higher codepoints take up two codeunits.

Your wide string consists of only **ASCII** characters, which are less than 0x0080 so they use no more than 7 bits each, leaving at least 9 bits set to 0. Thus, every other byte written to the file has a value of 0x00, which is not a displayable character, thus the extra spacing you are seeing.

Your wide string `L"ReplaceFile:"` consists of the following bytes in UTF-16LE:

```
0x52 0x00 // R
0x65 0x00 // e
0x70 0x00 // p
0x6C 0x00 // l
0x61 0x00 // a
0x63 0x00 // c
0x65 0x00 // e
0x46 0x00 // F
0x69 0x00 // i
0x6C 0x00 // l
0x65 0x00 // e
0x3A 0x00 // :
```

You should read the following article:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

With that said, UTF-16 is not the best choice for storing a string in a file. UTF-8 is more condensed than UTF-16 for most languages, and it is backwards compatible with ASCII.  On Windows, you can use the [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) function (or similar function/library) to convert your wide string before writing it to the file:

```
WCHAR msg[] = L"ReplaceFile:";
int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, msg, lstrlenW(msg), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
CHAR *converted = new CHAR[len];
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, msg, lstrlenW(msg), converted, len, NULL, NULL);
::WriteFile( hFile, converted, len * sizeof(CHAR), &nBytes, NULL );  
delete [] converted;
```

Comment: "Can somebody tell me how to make it normal and why?". It looks like you answered the ***why*** but not the ***how to make it normal***.

Comment: There is nothing abnormal about it. It's a perfectly normal and standard encoding. What he should have asked is "how to encode it in a way that does not have the extra nulls/spaces in it". The answer is to use `WideCharToMultiByte()` or similar function to convert the wide string from UTF-16 to a more condensed encoding, like UTF-8.

Comment: @RemyLebeau or define original string as `const char *` instead of `WCHAR` lol

Comment: `char msg[] = "ReplaceFile:";` would save a bunch of dreck

Comment: Of course, adding a BOM to the beginning of the file would be an alternative solution since it would help convince any decent text editor to interpret the data properly as UTF-16 and display what the user most likely expects.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wasn't saying there was anything abnormal about it. I just thought your answer would be more complete if you explained how to encode it without the extra spaces. I see you updated your answer, +1.